# Create Multiple editable combo boxes

Tags: excel, combobox

I've created multiple combo boxes (by copying and pasting the original one) in order to be able to select certain names of employees (in this case supervisor assigned and process reviewer).

This can be seen in the following picture:

[image: Excel Sheet]

However, this method has a limitation. It doesn't allow me to add new employees for example (without deleting all the combo boxes and copying and pasting everything again) and also it can be tedious to copy/paste combo boxes down the list especially with thousands of clients. The question is: Is it possible to improve this method in excel? Or it's a limitation and I should try to use SQL or Access?

Comment: I think it would be easier for us to answer the question if the header of the tables in your screenshot would be in english.

Comment: Not sure, but could it be that you are looking for a simple data validation? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2aTuK7fJxw

Comment: @Ralph I think that actually might solve my problem! It's also a way easier way to deal with it. Thank you very much!